# unwanted new line in console C programming

Tags: c

I am writing this small program in C and I am getting an unwanted new line. This is basically the part of my program that writes output and handles input:

```
    printf("\nGissning: ");
    scanf("%f",&gissning);

    if(gissning < RandomTal) {
        printf(" Du gissade för lågt, försök igen!");
    } else if(gissning > RandomTal){
        printf(" Du gissade för högt, försök igen!");
    }
```

This is what the output look like:

```
Gissning: 56
 Du gissade för lågt, försök igen!
Gissning:
```

This is what I want my output to look like:

```
Gissning: 56 Du gissade för lågt, försök igen!
Gissning:
```

So basically when I enter a number in this case 56 I press enter to give the computer the number and in the same time create a new row. I do not want this to happen. How do I solve this?

My teacher showed this command but I do not get it to work

```
while(getchar()!='\n');
```

Comment: Is this in Linux console, DOS Prompt, or other? What is the platform in other words.

Comment: Basically there is no way to achieve this with standard C. You'll have to use Windows console API, ncurses etc.

Comment: I am using XCode

Comment: @J.Doe So you have a Mac. This random find with Google may be of help: https://rhardih.io/2010/04/using-ncurses-in-c-for-text-user-interfaces-featuring-xcode/